# Finding an Uber at Berlin Brandenburg Airport during a lockdown?

Tags: international-travel, germany, covid-19, taxis

I have to travel to Berlin and will arrive at the new Berlin Brandenburg Airport, which, compared to the Tegel airport, is quite far away. Considering that there is reduced travel and a national lockdown, how hard is it to find an Uber from the airport to the city center?

Comment: What does the Uber App say? What about regular Taxi cab? What about the "S-Bahn" train? No option at all?

Comment: I can’t use Uber here because it’s not available. So when I go on the app, it redirects me to their local partner. I also can’t take the s-Bahn or bus because I have heavy luggage bags that are too heavy to carry. Which is why I asked here

Comment: Just take a cab. That's what they're for, and there's always some waiting at the airport.

Comment: Also, the way how Uber operates in Germany is different than e.g. in the US. Here they don't use private drivers, but rather contracted car-for-hire companies (not sure if that's the proper name for them, basically companies where you can hire a car with a driver) and use them, hence also why it's likely a bit more expensive than compared to the US.

Comment: If you manage to get your bags to the taxi stand, then you'd also manage to get them on the train, there is little, if at all, difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can look it up directly in the Uber app:

[image]

Currently 10 minutes waiting time and a few Uber around.

Comment: Thanks for this! But dang 50€? Phew. It’s getting expensive.

Comment: Then take the S-Bahn....
Honestly, even with bags. If you can manage to get your bags to the Uber pick up you should be able to manage getting them to the S-Bahn station as well. S-Bahn trains have level boarding, so you just roll your suitcase on and off...